# Doing JQuery Validation on CheckBoxListFor HTML Helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I'm using the `CheckBoxListFor` Helper - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension#AdvancedSettings

I have the following in my **View**

```
@using MvcCheckBoxList.Model
@model Web.Models.RegistrationViewModel

 <div>
    @Html.Label("Check at least one box:")
    <br />
                      @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.PostedAgentTypes.AgentTypeId,
                          model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.AvailableAgentTypes,
                          agent=>agent.Id,
                          agent=>agent.Name,
                          model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.SelectedAgentTypes,
                          Position.Horizontal)
    </div>
```

This works just fine; I'm able to see 4 check boxes and when checked it will identify them for me via the index of that check box.

I just wish to add some JQuery validation in order to display an error if the user does not choose any one of these check boxes.

I can add an `id` but I'm assuming this will add the same `id` to all 4 check boxes that get generated in the view. So I see that as a problem:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.PostedAgentTypes.AgentTypeId,
                  model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.AvailableAgentTypes,
                  agent=>agent.Id,
                  agent=>agent.Name,
                  model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.SelectedAgentTypes,
                  Position.Horizontal,
                  x=> new {id="agentTypesCheckboxes"}
                  )
```

My question here is, would it be possible to just do some server side validation on this via `DataAnnotations` to make sure at least one is checked? Or would it be recommended to do this via jQuery (as am trying to do now), how can it be done?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I've added the following code but no success, I click on one of the checkboxs, uncheck it and it shows no errors. Even after submitting the form, still no validation warnings on the checkboxes.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(obj) {
            var isValid = $("#RegistrationForm").valid();
            if (isValid) {
                obj.preventDefault();
                $('#RegistrationForm').submit();
                return false;
            }
        });

        $.validator.addMethod("chkGroupSelection", function () {
            return ($('#divChkGroup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length != 0);
        }, "Checkbox not selected.");

        $('#RegistrationForm').validate({
            rules: {
                divChkGroup: { chkGroupSelection: true }
            },
            messages: {
                divChkGroup: "Must check one"
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
            }
        });

    });
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Also probably worth noting, this is what the actual html looks like for one of the checkboxes I'm referring to.

```
<input id="agentTypeViewModel_PostedAgentTypes_AgentTypeId4" type="checkbox" value="5" name="agentTypeViewModel.PostedAgentTypes.AgentTypeId">
<label for="agentTypeViewModel_PostedAgentTypes_AgentTypeId4">Item 5</label>
```

Seems a bit weird format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what other input types are available on your page, you can use something like

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0){
    //fail validation
}
```

**Edit:** To clarify (for myself), if these are the only inputs on your current page, then my snippet should be sufficient.  If you have additional checkboxes that don't require this validation, you'll want to be more specific in the selector.

**Edit 2:** Let's call the encapsulating div divChkGroup.  Your code would then look like this:

```
if ($('#divChkGroup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0){
    //fail validation
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do have another checkbox that does not relate to these four. Maybe encapsulating the four checkboxes within a div and giving it an id would help? How would you do that with your example?

Comment: Check my updated post, still fighting with this. I've implemented your code within jQuery validate but without success.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on your return, what is the value of $('#divChkGroup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length?

Comment: At page load, it shows 0 (as it should) but I don't see it firing again after clicking on one of the checkboxes.

Comment: It won't fire on clicking a checkbox.  It should fire on submit or before submit.  You may have crossed wiring.

Comment: Yeah, i can see what it is.  You're calling $('#RegistrationForm').validate in document.ready.  That should be called in button click.

Comment: The reasoning behind that: Every time you click the submit button, you need to validate.  What you are currently doing is just checking the value of valid which was set one time on page load.  Right above var isValid = ... you should do the call to validate and then just keep doing what you're doing.

Comment: Not sure what is up but this just will not work. I tried what you stated, but nothing. Every other validation works without me even submitting the form though. For example, if I enter `123` for e-mail it will instantly highlight red and advise that its not a valid e-mail, until I replace it with a proper email then it goes away. It seems to be a pain in the ass to get the same working for `CheckBoxListFor`.

Comment: Thank you smd, I got it to work with the snippet you provided :) Ended up doing it manually instead of using jQuery validation. I created a `span`, gave it an `id` and checked if any checkboxes were checked at form submission; if not then I stop the form submission and display validation message next to checkboxes.